# iOS MPRemoteCommandCenter when switching between audio and video stream

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am working on a music/video streaming app, and I'm using `AVPlayer` to load up the videos and songs.

I have a singleton instance of my music player class that handles music playback. I have included a code snippet with the relevant audio session and command center setup:

```
let audio_Session: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try audio_Session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try audio_Session.setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canBecomeFirstResponder() {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().becomeFirstResponder()
        }

let now_Playing_Command: MPRemoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter()
        now_Playing_Command.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pause_Command))
        now_Playing_Command.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.play_Command))
        now_Playing_Command.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.next_Track_Command))
        now_Playing_Command.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggle_Play_Pause))
        now_Playing_Command.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.previous_Track_Command))
```

Everything works fine UNTIL I start streaming a video. During video playback, the command center begins accepting pause/play commands for the video, which pause/resume the video. Sometimes, it causes the song to resume playing in the background.

This is the sequence:

1. begin streaming song
2. pause song
3. begin streaming video
4. end video
5. but when i resume the song playback (via the view controller controls), the `MPCommandCenter` buttons are grayed out and I cant set them. Starting a new song (which does most of the setup for audio session and such) does not work either.

Starting a video and ending it before any song is played grays out the command center buttons for all future song streams' .

I would like to be able to program the command center to seamlessly transition from receiving remote commands from music (singleton instance) to a video (regular instance) and back to the paused Singleton instance song.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I'm posting here since it might help someone in the future.

My songs playback is handled by a custom sharedInstance singleton instance of AVPlayer, which I built myself.

I also created a custom `AVPlayerViewController`, which only handles the video playback and is stateless, so when the user dismisses the video, its gone forever.

From my parent VC, I instantiated and displayed my custom `AVPlayerViewController`, which is only for the video.

```
let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

        //Create View Controllers
        let video_VC:VideoViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("video_View_Controller") as! VideoViewController

        video_VC.url = url
        video_VC.video_Holder = video_Holder
        video_VC.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)


        self.presentViewController(video_VC, animated: true, completion: { void in
            video_VC.player?.play()
        })`
```

Then, in my `AVPlayerViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, I checked to see if my singleton instance of audio player is has any songs playing/paused. If so, I set a variable in that singleton instance called `is_Variable_Open` to `true`. At that point, the music player functions will ignore all command center commands. Furthermore, I enable the command buttons again and set them to this instance of `AVPlayerViewController`, which only handles the video stream.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
if(media().sharedInstance.playerItem != nil){
            print("there is a song playing, so lets pause it")
            media().sharedInstance.is_Video_Player_Open = true
            if(media().sharedInstance.player?.rate == 1){
                media().sharedInstance.player.pause()
            }

            let now_Playing_Command: MPRemoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter()
            now_Playing_Command.pauseCommand.enabled = true
            now_Playing_Command.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pause_Command))
            now_Playing_Command.playCommand.enabled = true
            now_Playing_Command.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.play_Command))
            now_Playing_Command.togglePlayPauseCommand.enabled = true
            now_Playing_Command.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.toggle_Play_Pause))
```

And then upon dismissal of the video, in `viewWillDisappear`, I set the variable `is_Video_Player_Open` back to `false`, and tell the music player to set its command center setup again. BAM.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("video player is about to disapear")

        if(media().sharedInstance.playerItem != nil){
            print("video is about to end, and there is ssog playing, so lets do stuff")
            media().sharedInstance.is_Video_Player_Open = false
            media().sharedInstance.set_MP_Command()
            media().sharedInstance.set_Now_Playing()
        }
    }
```